# Creating observable object to handle json data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is how I have json currently implemented

I load my data into my ContentView with `@State var bookData: [Book] = load("list")`. Whenever I need to update my data in a different view I use a binding to the original and JsonEconder function with code like this `@Binding var bookData: [Book]` and

```swift
Button(action: {
    bookData.append(Book(id: UUID(), name: name, author: author,genre: genre, page: page, total: total))
    bookData = sortData(sorted: sorted, sort: sort, order: order, oldData: bookData)
    writeJSON(bookData)
}) {
   Text("Add book")
}
```

This way of handling the data works just fine however after some research, using an observable object might be a better approach.

Here are all my function, they lie in a swift file called Data.swift

```swift
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {

    let readURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")!
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent(filename)
        .appendingPathExtension("json")

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.path) {
        try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: readURL, to: jsonURL)
    }
    return try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(contentsOf: jsonURL))
}

func writeJSON(_ bookData: [Book]) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent("list")
        .appendingPathExtension("json")
    try? JSONEncoder().encode(bookData).write(to: jsonURL, options: .atomic)
}

func sortData(sorted: Bool, sort: String, order: String, oldData: [Book]) -> [Book] {
    var bookData: [Book] = oldData
    if sorted == true{
        if sort == "Name"{
            if order == "A"{
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
            } else {
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {$0.name > $1.name})
            }
        }
        if sort == "Author"{
            if order == "A"{
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {$0.author < $1.author})
            } else {
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {$0.author > $1.author})
            }
        }
        if sort == "Page"{
            if order == "A"{
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {Int($0.page) ?? 0 < Int($1.page) ?? 0})
            } else {
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {Int($0.page) ?? 0 > Int($1.page) ?? 0})
            }
        }
        if sort == "Length"{
            if order == "A"{
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {Int($0.total)! > Int($1.total)!})
            } else {
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {Int($0.total)! < Int($1.total)!})
            }
        }
        if sort == "Genre"{
            if order == "A"{
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {$0.genre < $1.genre})
            } else {
                bookData = oldData.sorted(by: {$0.genre > $1.genre})
            }
        }
    }
    return bookData
}
```

Note: The sortData function uses user setting store in userdefaults.

I tried creating a class like this but I got the error "'self' used in method call 'load' before all stored properties are initialized"

```swift
class jsonData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bookData: [Book]

    init(bookData: [Book]){
        self.bookData = load("list")
    }

    func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
        let readURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")!
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let jsonURL = documentDirectory
            .appendingPathComponent(filename)
            .appendingPathExtension("json")

        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.path) {
            try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: readURL, to: jsonURL)
        }
        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(contentsOf: jsonURL))
        }
}
```

Overall I have an array of structs stored as a json array that is displayed in a form on the homepage, there are other views that add, edit or delete objects in the array. How can I create and use an observable object to replace my current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to place `load(_:)` function outside of `ObservableObject`. You can add `load(_:)` function inside `Bundle` extension and it is able to be reused everywhere you want. Error will go away. Here is my sample code.

```
class jsonData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bookData: [Book]

    init() {
        self.bookData = Bundle.load("list")
    }

    // other functions
}

extension Bundle {
    static func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
        let readURL = main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")!
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let jsonURL = documentDirectory
            .appendingPathComponent(filename)
            .appendingPathExtension("json")

        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.path) {
            try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: readURL, to: jsonURL)
        }
        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(contentsOf: jsonURL))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason making it a bundle extension is better than just leaving it in a swift file.

Comment: Extension is used to add new functionality to an existing struct, class, enum or protocol. Here `load(_:)` method is a new function that mainly uses `Bundle` class. That's why I just add that method to `Bundle` extension. I prefer adding a reusable code to extension than in a separate file. But you can make it as global if you wish.